# scrollTop in android does not report correctly

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am running Android 4.2.1, jquery, and using PhoneGap 2.9.  I have a simple scroll detection, i think.  I am dynamically adding elements to the `body` of a page.  If the user is already at the bottom of the element, it should automatically scroll.  If the user is scrolled up to another portion, it should not scroll.  This is the code I am trying:

```
var b = $("body");
var oldscroll = b.scrollTop();

b.scrollTop(oldscroll + 1);

var newscroll = $("body").scrollTop();

var scroll = oldscroll == newscroll;

 if(scroll)
    //scroll to bottom.
```

No matter where the person has scrolled, if that check is done, `scroll` always comes out `true`.  I am starting to wonder if the comparison is being done before the scroll finishes.  I put this code in to a desktop Chrome browser, and it works without issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19625

Comment: I dont know if that applies @adeneo, if i just set the scrollTop, it does move the scroll position.